# Select All Listview Checkbox

Tags: android

I have  checkbox in a listview android. I would like that a button is clicked, all checkboxes are checked/unchecked. I have the below code. This only checks checkboxes in screen view leaving the rest. any suggestion

```
ListView lv;
........


  CheckBox all = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.selectAll);
            all.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton k, boolean isChecked) {
                  if(k.isChecked()){
                      for(int i=0 ; i < lv.getChildCount() ; i++) {
                          CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) lv.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.contactcheck);
                          cb.setChecked(true);
                      }

                  }else{
                      for(int i=0 ; i < lv.getChildCount() ; i++) {
                          CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) lv.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.contactcheck);
                          cb.setChecked(false);
                      }`enter code here`
                  }
                }
            });
```

Any suggestion on how to check all items in list view and not just in the screen view

Answer (score 0):

The best to achieve this according to me is to follow these steps given below:

1. Add a variable let's say named "isChecked" in your "RowModel" class and set if to false by default when adding items in your "Arraylist".
2. In your Adapter "getView()" define a condition, in which you will check if that variable's value is "true" then set the checkbox to "setChecked = true" otherwise false.
3. In your Main class, on the click of button set the value of the "ischecked = true" for your whole arraylist with a loop.
4. Call the method "youradapter.notifyDataSetChangede()".

It's done!

PS: One more suggestion, always use "ViewHolder" sub-class in your Adapter class.